# How to create a Quarkus application executable on Windows?

Tags: docker, quarkus, graalvm, quarkus-native

How to create a Quarkus application executable on Windows?

I have created a first Quarkus app from its initializer https://code.quarkus.io/

I have been able to do correctly all the steps indicated in the README.md except the creation of an native executable.

To be more precise, I have been able to create it, but I have not been able to run it, because it seems that the executable that is created is for Linux:

*<<The produced executable will be a 64-bit Linux executable, so depending on your operating system it may no longer be runnable. However, it’s not an issue as we are going to copy it to a Docker container. Note that in this case the build itself runs in a Docker container too, so you don’t need to have GraalVM installed locally.>>*

1. Running the application in dev mode:

   mvnw compile quarkus:dev
2. Packaging and running the application as a jar:

   mvnw package
   java -jar target/quarkus-app/quarkus-run.jar
3. Packaging and running the application as an uber-jar:

   mvnw package -Dquarkus.package.type=uber-jar
   java -jar target/*-runner.jar
4. Creating a native executable in a container: (because I don't have GraalVM)

   mvnw package -Pnative -Dquarkus.native.container-build=true

Comment: I did such in the past, along with a gitlab pipeline that builds the windows native image. You can check my repo for inspiration https://gitlab.com/bosacky/lego-crawler/-/blob/master/.gitlab-ci.yml

Comment: I appreciate the information, but I lack the level to take advantage of it

Comment: there are few prerequisites on windows (I mentioned in my readme):
1. Install Visual Studio with C (MSVC is necessary)
2. Run x64 Native Tools Command Prompt for VS 2019
3. Run `mvn -DskipTests package -Pnative` from that command line

Comment: Okay, I'll try it later. Well lately I'm installing too many things on my computer. Thanks!

Comment: I put screen shots at the bottom of this [page](https://ozkanpakdil.github.io/quarkus,graalvm/2021/11/03/quarkus-build-native-windows.html) it may help